# Property value is not valid - A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, gdi+, picturebox

I'm trying to run a 10 years old C# Visual Studio project

For some reason, I can't remove nor edit any of the images inside the forms

If I try to edit the image property of a PictureBox while using the view designer I get a "Property value is not valid" error. The details box reads "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Even changing the PictureBox's size triggers the same error

Although it isn't that relevant, here's the form's code. Seems to me like it's just the auto generated code from the View Designer:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace AppCliente.Vista
{
    public class frmLogin : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox picLogin;
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        private frmLogin()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();      
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.picLogin = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picLogin)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // picLogin
            // 
            this.picLogin.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-1, -3);
            this.picLogin.Name = "picLogin";
            this.picLogin.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(264, 48);
            this.picLogin.TabIndex = 5;
            this.picLogin.TabStop = false;
            this.picLogin.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.picLogin_Click);       
            this.Controls.Add(this.picLogin); 
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picLogin)).EndInit();

        }


        private void picLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What could be causing this?

If it is of any use, I get the following error if I try to compile the project:

```
The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(MemoryStream stream)
   at System.Drawing.Image.System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo si, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.WriteValue(ResourceTypeCode typeCode, Object value, BinaryWriter writer, IFormatter objFormatter)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Generate()
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Close()
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo reader, IResourceWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo reader, String filename)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile, String outFileOrDir)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 outputs, Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 outputs, Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() AppCliente
```

Comment: According to your InitializeComponent, the PictureBox doesn't have an image.

Comment: Just added a couple missing lines

Comment: PictureBox still doesn't have an image.  If resizing the control in the designer is triggering the same exception, something else is going on that we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the target framework to .Net 2.0 I started getting more meaningful error messages
Turns out the .resx files of various forms were corrupt, so deleting them solved the issue